# Write a single byte to the serial port with Bash

Tags: bash, shell, arduino

I have an Arduino which I have coded to read from a USB serial port and power an LED.
I know it is working because it works on the built serial monitor. Now I want to write a Bash script which writes to the serial port.

Here is the command:

```
 echo 121 > /dev/cu.usbmodem411
```

It outputs the string "123". How can I instead write a single byte with a value of 121?

Comment: Thanks that was right I found my problem. If I pass 121 it writes an integer. If I put "y" it will it will write 121 as a byte which is what I want.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
echo 121 > /dev/cu.usbmodem411
```

will write four bytes: 0x31 (meaning '1'), 0x32 (meaning '2'), 0x31 again, 0x0A (meaning a newline).

If your goal is to write a single byte, with value 121, you would write this:

```
echo -n $'\171' > /dev/cu.usbmodem411
```

where 171 is 121 expressed in base-8, and `-n` tells `echo` not to print a newline character.

If that's *not* your goal, then please clarify.

Comment: or you can also use the **hex** notation when sending the value: `echo -en '\x79' > /dev/cu.usbmodem411`